# Are positive and negative angles defined for three dimensions

Tags: coordinate-systems

In two dimensions, the anticlockwise direction is considered to be positive and the clockwise direction is considered to be negative. Does this hold even for angles in 3 dimensions?

Comment: It is a matter of orientations.  You could define a solid angle as the area enclosed by a loop on the unit sphere.  If you went round the loop in the opposite direction then you might get a negative solid angle or something $4\pi $ minus your original solid angle; this would be analogous in two dimensions to going in the opposite direction on an arc and getting a negative  angle or something $2\pi$ minus your original angle

Answer (score 0):

In 3 dimensions, you'll have to specify the axis of rotation.  This means that you have 3 vectors involved:  The two vectors $a$, $b$ for which you want to determine the angle, and the axis $r$ around which you are rotating.

Whether the rotation is clockwise or anti-clockwise is a matter of definition.  For example, if you look at a clockwise rotation from above, then it will be anti-clockwise when you look at it from below.  This is the reason for why you need a 3rd vector (or some other means) to determine clockwise-ness.

One way to determine whether a rotation is clockwise, could be to define clockwise-ness depending on whether

$$\operatorname{sign}(\det(a, b, r)) \tag1$$

is $1$, $-1$ or $0$.  where $0$ basically means *"undefined"*.  The latter case occurs when one vector is 0, or when $a=\lambda b$, that is if the angle is $0^\circ$ or $180^\circ$.  It also occurs if $r$ is in the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$.

Notice that $\det$ is alternating multi-linear, thus the sign of $(1)$ will flip when $a$, $b$, $r$ are permutated by an odd permitation.  It also flips when one of the involved dectors is replaced by its negative, for example flipping $r$ will flip clockwise-ness: $$\operatorname{sign}(\det(a, b, -r)) = -\operatorname{sign}(\det(a, b, r)) $$
etc.

Also notice that one $r$ won't work for all $a$ and $b$.  For example, if $a$, $b$ and $r$ are linerly dependent, then you'll get the *"undefined"* case.  This means you are looking at the rotation edge-on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time out of your day to answer the question. Really appreciate it:)